# How to read text in Span tag when multiple span in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

```
<td class="rich-tabpanel-content" style="; ">
   <div id="page:form1:block1:j_id738" style="width:75%;">
      <span xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" id="page:form1:block1:out">
         <b>
         <span style="text-align:right;font-size:15px;color:black">Risk Value</span>
         </b>  
         <b>
         <span style="text-align:right;font-size:15px;color:black"></span>
         <span style="text-align:right;font-size:14px;color:blue">Select a value for every risk.</span>
         </b>
      </span> 
   </div>
</td>
```

I'm using

```
String str = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[id^='page:form1:block1:j_id738'] span ")).getText();
```

but it is fetching only the Risk Value but not the other text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `driver.findElements` rather than `driver.findElement`.

try something like this:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div[id^='page:form1:block1:j_id738'] span"));
```

then loop through this list and call `getText()` on each element to retrieve the text i.e:

if you're using Java:

```
for (WebElement element : elements) {
     String data = element.getText();
     // do something with data
}
```

if you're using C#:

```
foreach (WebElement element in elements) {
     string data = element.getText();
     // do something with data
}
```

Comment: Tried this but the second text is not being fetched

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple span tag inside your desired section. So you have to use **findElements** method instead of using **findElement**. **findElements** returns the list of elements residing inside the specified css or className. So your code should look like --

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div[id^='page:form1:block1:j_id738'] span"));
for (WebElement element : elements) {
  System.out.println(element.getText());  
}
```